# QBrush texture without tiling

Tags: qt, textures, qpainter, qimage

Is there an easy way to get rid of tiling when using a QBrush with texture?

```
QImage*   texture = CreateQImage();       // create texture
QBrush*   brush   = new QBrush(*texture); // create texture brush
QPainter* painter = CreateQPainter();     // create painter

painter->fillRectangle(0, 0, 500, 500, *brush);
```

Suppose we have a QImage texture with size of 20x20 pixels. The code above will tile this texture all across the rectangle being filled. Is there an easy way to draw only a single instance of this texture? The QBrush usage is crucial.

Theoretically, I could reload every fill and draw method of the QPainter that takes a QBrush as input and use a

```
QPainter.drawImage()
```

method, but I think there must be a simplier way.

Thanks, Tony.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is (see [Qt::BrushStyle](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qt.html#BrushStyle-enum) - the only style with a texture tiles it), and it wouldn't really make sens IMO. If you just want one image, use the `drawImage` functions as you've stated.

(One of the problems with not tiling is: what do you fill the rest of the rectangle with? Nothing? Some default background color? Some other `QBrush` attribute?)

Comment: Yeah, the rest of the rectangle won't be filled at all. I want to achieve the same result as [WrapModeClamp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534407(v=vs.85).aspx) in GDI+ does.